# New to gravity forms and php - field validation example parameter question

Tags: php, gravityforms

The field validation code starts with :
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_175_1', 'custom_validation', **10, 4** );

I need to understand what **10, 4** relates to.  I can read the code and understand the form and field selection and what it is doing, I just don't understand what the parameters 10 and 4 are relating to.

I know this is a basic beyond belief question, but I am wary of implementing until I know what each piece is.  I've also seen 10,5 as well.

Thank you in advance for your help...I hope you didn't spit your soda all over your keyboard.  :)

I haven't tried to implement this as I don't understand every piece of it.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter 10 in this case is the priority of the filter. It means if multiple functions are attached to the same hook, the priority determines the order in which they shoule be executed. Note that a lower number means higher priority.

The fourth parameter 4 in this case is the number of arguments that the custom function expects to receive when it is called. In the case of the gform_field_validation hook, it passes four arguments to the attached functions. These arguments contain information about the form field being validated, the form object, the current value of the field, and the form submission object.

you can find more details about the function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)